# Origin of the common M'chalkel niggun

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, music, provenance

There is a niggun, which I personally find rather inane, for the main paragraph of the second brachah of the Amidah. I have never been in a schul where it is not sung (. I have heard other niggunim though, such as the version which follows the nusach, the "Fiddler on the Roof" niggun used by Chabad, and other assorted ones). [Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mi0aOOiv-4&spfreload=10) of it being sung by a Conservative chazzan (he's using the Siddur Sim Shalom).

What is the origin of this niggun and how did it become so commonplace?

Comment: Argh! Now I can't get it out of my head!

Comment: Sorry, @Shalom, I just needed people to know that that was the one I was talking about. I did warn that it was inane, though.

Comment: Is it just me or does he pronounce a Dalet as the "th" in "the"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I only listened long enough to verify that this was the melody in question. It is possible that he pronounced the ד that way, although it's unlikely unless he's Temani.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, yes he does.

Comment: I have never heard it!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, you are quite lucky.